# Unable to upload all files on webdav server using webclient and httpwebrequest C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, webdav

```
public int UploadFile(string url, string localFile,out string a_Error)
{
WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
webClient.Proxy = null;

webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Credential.UserName, Credential.Password);
webClient.UploadFile(url, "PUT", localFile);
webClient.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list - just including a title and then code is not sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Try using HttpWebRequest class.
Here are examples:
[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734404/error-using-httpwebrequest-to-upload-files-with-put)
[Second](http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/02/09/sending-webdav-requests-in-net.aspx)