# Powershell: WriteErrorException on upload of file to SharePoint using System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to upload a file from local to SharePoint using below piece of code. But somehow this error message is thrown which leaves me wondering about the cause:

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): 
"An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :              Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,CopyFileToSharePoint.ps1
```

Anybody any ideas?

- The user running the script has permissions to upload a file, e.g. using IE interactively.
- And no, this is a remote server, thus I cannot use Microsoft.SharePoint classes.

The code

```
#Copy the file to the destination on SharePoint using WebClient
$SourceFile = $SourcePath + "\" + $FileName
$DestinationFile = $DestinationPath + "/" + $FileName

$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.UseDefaultCredentials=$true

if ( -not (Test-Path $DestinationPath) ) {
New-Item $DestinationPath -Type Directory  | Out-Null
}

$result |% {
Write-Host "Uploading $SourceFile to $DestinationFile"

try{
    $client.UploadFile($SourceFile, $DestinationFile)
}
catch{
    #one simple retry...
    try{
        $client.UploadFile($SourceFile, $DestinationFile)
    }
    catch{
        write-error "Failed to upload $SourceFile, $_"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably irrelevant but your retry is 'downloading' file not uploading. Error says you are passing 3 arguments. Can you print $sourceFile and $DestinationFile? What does it look like?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. Copied a local version with that typo still in there. Second DownloadFile should be uploadfile. I fixed the original post (i know, dubious but adds clarity in this thread)

Comment: $SourceFile: D:\temp\test.csv   $DestinationFile=http://sharepoint/Test%20Doclib/test.csv

Comment: Hmm, something is not right. $DestinationFile cannot be set like that, right? I have suspicion that %20 (space char) is your problem there and causing the upload to think your path is 3 part. Can you print $DestinationFile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! What finally seemed to work, was setting the contenttype:

```
$client.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

That somehow resolved the issue.
Got the idea to try from this thread:
[Error using HttpWebRequest to upload files with PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734404/error-using-httpwebrequest-to-upload-files-with-put)

Answer (score 1):

Also, the file you uploading should be 'Checked Out' in the  SharePoint Library before run the UploadFile command. If not, UploadFile throws the above MethodException error of 3 arguments. I recreated this error manually toggling the SharePoint Library settings 'Allow Documents to be checked out before editing?'.
But I don't know if we can do the check out/in using System.Net.WebClient programatically. (Din't find anything in the Documentation though)